# Angularjs error - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I am a AngularJS beginner and I am using Angular 1.3.15 and I am facing the below error when  I try to execute a simple script

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Html

```
<title>AngularJS data binding</title>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

```
<div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">

    Name :
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>{{name |uppercase}}
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="personName in names">{{personName}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

JS file -

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['test1','test2'];


});
})();
```

Does the code in the file `myscript.js` has to be in the `(function()})` ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you minifying the js file ? i  guess yes :)

Comment: Yes I am using the minified angularjs file

Comment: `(function () {})()` is an Immediately Invoked Function. This means that any variables declared inside will be scoped to just that execution rather than the entire javascript environment.

Comment: Yes, coming from the jquery background I was thinking the same, but is this approach useful in large projects as AngularJS provided 2 way data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are minifying the `js` files then

```
app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['test1','test2'];
});
```

this becomes something like

```
x.controller('SimpleController', function(a) {
    a.a = ['test1','test2'];
});
```

then there is no `$scope` in the controller so use like,

```
app.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['test1','test2'];
}]);
```

then angular will solve the arguments you pass to functions,

for example:

```
 app.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function(a) {
    a.names = ['test1','test2'];
}]);
```

angular will match the `a` to the `$scope` property.

Comment: To get a complete error I used non-minified version of the angularJS and now it says " Module 'myapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." . Whereas the HTMl tag contains - <html ng-app="myapp">

Comment: nope not the `angular.js` file, check your custom `JS files`

Comment: Ok great glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Error is coming due to minification. Try this

JS:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('SimpleController',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['test1','test2'];


}]);
})();
```

The way you try is minification proof, read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Comment: You mean Minification and not magnification? :)